# NSString "nil or empty" check -- is this complete?

Tags: objective-c

I was writing a small Category on NSString, and I wanted to know if this method is accurately handles all potential use cases:

**Update:** to clarify -- I wanted to make sure I'm not missing some oddball case involving character encodings, etc..

```
@implementation NSString (Helpers)

+(BOOL)stringIsNilOrEmpty:(NSString*)aString {
    if (!aString)
        return YES;
    return [aString isEqualToString:@""];
}
@end
```

Sample usage:

```
-(void) sampleUsage {
    NSString *emptyString = @"";
    NSString *nilString = nil;
    NSAssert([NSString stringIsNilOrEmpty:nilString] == YES, @"String is nil/empty");
    NSAssert([NSString stringIsNilOrEmpty:emptyString] == YES, @"String is nil/empty");
}
@end
```

Comment: That will work.  There are a dozen different ways to check for "empty" -- length == zero is another.

Comment: In fact, you can (shudder) use just one test:  `if ([aString length] == 0) return YES;`.  This makes use of the Objective-C "feature" that any method call off of a nil pointer returns zero.

Comment: (And, of course, you can shorten that to `return [aString length] == 0;`)

Comment: Actually `aString.length` saves another two character spaces.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I only use the next conditional and do not even need a category:

```
if (!aString.length)
{
    ...
}
```

Using Objective-C theory, a message to NIL will return nil or zero, so basically **you do not have to test for nil**.

Comment: !aString.length is true when aString is nil, I don't know why. But `aString.length != 0` works for me!

Comment: That's exactly what it should be - true for nil string.

Comment: length is a function and your code is wrong for objective c.

Answer (score 30):

You can simplify the code by removing conditional:

```
+(BOOL)stringIsNilOrEmpty:(NSString*)aString {
    return !(aString && aString.length);
}
```

Comment: Couple of nit-picks : Dot syntax should really be used for properties, not methods. Length is a method. As an added bonus, if you call length correctly you don't have to check for nil ever again in regards to strings. So, you can `return [aString length] == 0;` This works because calling length on a nil will return 0.

Answer (score 10):

@dasblinkenlight's answer is fine, but a much more readable conditional check I would use is:

```
NSString *string = ...;   // define the string
if ([string length] == 0) {
    // Do stuff with the string
} else {
    // The string is empty or nil here
}
```

Very concise and does not require a separate convenience function definition. It's easy enough to remember.

EDIT: @Michael G. Emmons posted this as the last comment to that answer... credit to him but I'm listing this as an answer in its own right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   The question was about the correct implementation of a `isStringNilOrEmpty` method -- I wanted a single method that would check both conditions.

Comment: I believe your condition is reversed.

Answer (score 2):

Some examples of this sort of "is not empty or blank" tests as a category on NSString.

```
// Please note that in general I advocate using a prefix on category methods
// to avoid category collisions.  I've not done this here for clarity. 
// The @interface is also excluded from this example for brevity.

@implementation NSString (MyAdditions)

- (BOOL)isNotEmpty
{
  return [self length] != 0;
}

- (BOOL)isNotBlank
{
  if ([self isNotEmpty])
  {
    NSCharacterSet *nonWhitespaceSet = [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    NSRange range = [self rangeOfCharactersFromSet:nonWhitespaceSet];
    return range.location != NSNotFound;
  }

  return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: if the string is nil, those method will not be call.

Comment: @c0ming but the result will be right. Sending message to nil string will return NO as the result. In order to receive YES from this method string at least shouldn't be nil, then it should pass through the test.

Answer (score 0):

> Simply Check your string length
>
> ```
> > if (!yourString.length){
> >     //your code  } a
> ```
>
> message to NIL will return nil or 0, so no need to test for nil :).
>
> Happy coding ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check for spaces, trim white spaces before calculating length.

```
+(BOOL)stringIsNilOrEmpty:(NSString*)aString {
    return !aString || [[aString  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length] == 0;
}
```